# What does it mean: Let's cue the iceberg

Tags: expressions, american-english, phrase-usage

I was watching a webinar on cybersecurity, and heard following sentence from the speaker:

> ...So, let's cue the iceberg

Can someone please explain the above phrase with some context/example?

An [online search](https://www.google.com/search?q=cue%20the%20iceberg%20meaning&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS998US998&oq=cue%20the%20iceber&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j33i160l3.7122j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) did not help.

Comment: Quite possibly a reference to the Titanic. What was the wider context of the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with *cue*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cue)
> *cue*, noun
> a signal for someone to do something
> *cue* verb
> to give someone a signal to do something

The speaker is implying or referring to a signal for "the iceberg". But which iceberg? As pointed out in comment, one of the most significant and well-known icebergs, probably THE most significant in popular consciousness, is the one than holed the Titanic. It seemed to have little significance at first but proved lethal and hugely damaging.

The speaker is therefore introducing some cybersecurity theme that poses great peril, a peril out of proportion to what we first think about it.